# I beginn in music

Tags: theory, romantic-period

Since a lot of time, I'm more and more passionate by the romantic era (mostly by the works of Chopin and Liszt).

However, I like but I don't know why. So I would like to study the theory of music.

---

I know this must be heavy, so where to start?

Do you have good references? (PDF, book).

---

Here are some examples of questions I ask to myself :

-What's the difference (precisely in the structure) between : classics and romantics?

-What make Wagner or Liszt innovative?

-How to characterize the works of Chopin?

I'm not excepting an answer but I would like to know what to study to answer this by my self.

For now, I'm studying the book of THÉORIE DE LA MUSIQUE of A. DANHAUSER about music theory (I'm mathematician at side so I like when the things are well structured). I don't know if it's good or not.

Many thanks for your advice.

Comment: Welcome to Music: Practise & Theory. Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://music.stackexchange.com/help), especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). At the moment, this is far too broad to answer, and is requesting off-site resources, which is also off-topic.

Comment: Danhauser's theory book is probably worthwhile, but was written in the 19th century. There are modern textbooks that might be more readable, and would have a better "hindsight" on the romantic period. Also, many of your questions are more about music _history_ than theory. There are probably many good books about Wagner/Liszt/Chopin or the romantic period in general. You would probably enjoy a music history course focusing on the era.

Comment: Also, feel free to open other questions here that are focused on a single (well-defined) question like "What's the difference, specifically in structure, between classical and romantic period?" Or even edit this question to focus on one of those.

Comment: Hello Andy, thanks a lot. Do you have titles in mind? I'll try to post a more precise question next time, sorry.